# How can model variables can be shared in both Service class and controller class (typescript/angular)

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, typescript

I have a Controller class, Service class, and Model class. I want to know how I can have access to the same model in both Controller and Service classes.

**So for example :**

Controller Class :

```
import { SearchModel } from "../../models/SearchModel";
import { SearchService } from "../../components/SearchService";

export class SearchController {
    public searchModel: SearchModel;
    static $inject = ['searchService'];

    constructor(private searchService:SearchService) {
        this.searchService = searchService;
    }

    public controllerMethod() {
        console.log(this.searchModel.searchKeyword); //This works. 
        this.searchModel.searchKeyword = "CheckIfSharedObject";
        this.searchService.serviceMethod();
    }
}
```

Service Class :

```
import { SearchModel } from "../../models/SearchModel";

export class SearchService {
    public searchModel: SearchModel;

    constructor() { }

    public serviceMethod() {
        // This will not work. i.e this wont print 'CheckIfSharedObject'
        console.log(this.searchModel.searchKeyword);
    }
}
```

Model Class :

```
export class SearchModel {
    constructor (
        public searchKeyword: string
    )
}
```

From the above example, I want controller and service to share the model variable searchKeyword in both the classes.

It works when we pass the model class object to the serviceMethod, but I dont want to do that. Is there a way we can make it work without explicitly passing the Model Class Object to Service class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want controller and service to share the model variable searchKeyword in both the classes

It is okay to have `model` modelled using an *angularjs service*. That will make the model a singleton that can be shared between the controller and the service.

I would even in fact say that your service should really be the model. That way you will only have "controller" + "service", but feel free to have three things if you want.

Comment: If I use service , how it will solve my problem .  Because I want to access variables in my HTML . Model contents can be accessed from controller . If we create service , I need to access that variable as controllerName.ServiceName.variable . Main purpose of creating service is to hide logic from html. If you have any other way please suggest

Comment: `Main purpose of creating service is to hide logic from html` Your *controller* is available on html. Any attempt to hide stuff *available to the controller* from html is futile

Comment: thanks .. I have discussed with my leads and came to an understanding that service can be created. Thanks for the info.